# Weird issue in orthophoto of canpy in rough terrain

Tags: dem, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, orthophoto

After postprocessing drone imagery of a forest area in rough terrain, I had a weird issue such as in the images below.

The effect is like the cropping of trees following the DSM.

If you have encountered this issue, what it is exactly? And why does it happen?

The Orthophoto
[image: I]

The DSM
[image]

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to add more details, particularly what postprocessing steps, and what software you used.

Comment: Ditto to user2856 for more detail.  How much image overlap do you have for this area?